# Info about GE to use for a IoT mobility Project

Tags: fiware

I would to develop an IoT mobility project project using fi-ware.
My intention is to deploy a lot of sensor on the taxi/bus
in the city to control air quality.
I want to use IDAS GEi, but i have some questions:

I must use a linino board as gateway for my sensors.
How can i send observations or receive commands from
linino to IDAS and viceversa? I have found on the web this
tool: figway. I have read figway is used as communication 
gateway between raspberryPI and IDAS.
So i have thought to adapt figway for linino. Is it the correct way
to reach my goal? Are there better ways to do that?

Furthermore, i should provide discovery mechanisms and a transparent
interface to control the sensors. For example, i should provide to the user
the possibility to find the sensors, that provide a data measure, in a certain place.
I would to use SWE for that. Is IDAS swe compliant? I have read in the documentation
IDAS uses swe data model, sensorML, O&M but i have not found anything about 
SOS/SAS/SPS/WNS services.
Has IDAS discovery mechanisms? Maybe i must use other GE to do that (Configuration Manager?)

Comment: Stackoverflow works best when you ask one question (or problem) at a time. This way you can say that one answer it ok.

Comment: For the question how a user finds the sensors, my understanding is that this is what the orion context broker is intended to do.

Comment: @Meier Thanks, i'm newbie on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Figway is just a python example of how you can make the queries to the Ultralight 2.0 IoT-Agent.

You may port Figway to your new platform if it supports python or, alternatively you can check the HTTP POST requests to code at any other platform/language.
It is really easy, have a look at:   http://www.slideshare.net/FI-WARE/fiware-iotidasintroul20v2

Additionally, do not forget that Ultralight2.0/HTTP is one of the technology options that we support for IoT. If your devices are to use other standard such as MQTT/TCP or LWM2M/CoAP/UDP you can check other IoT-Agents (that connect as well to the same Orion contextbroker):

UL2.0 and MQTT are here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus
LWM2M is here: https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent

Also, if you want to use any other standard (or even your own propietary protocol) you may build up your own IoT Agent using the skeleton provided here:
 https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib

Thanks for using IDAS!
Cheers,